# SQL: if value exists then show else hide

Tags: sql

I have an SQL query that filters down purchase credit and invoices and removes any zero tax amounts, it has just come to light that there is some i need to include for me to get the correct figure. Luckily these few invoices and credit notes can be identified on there reference number, unfortunately i don not know how to write such a query. I am guessing it should be an `if` statement. Any help would be much appreciated, query is below.

```
SELECT 
 --T_PURCHASEINVOICE.C_ID, 
  T_PURCHASEINVOICE.C_DATE, 
  T_PURCHASEINVOICE.C_NUMBER, 
  T_PURCHASEINVOICE.C_NETAMOUNT  , 
  T_PURCHASEINVOICE.C_GROSSAMOUNT, 
  T_PURCHASEINVOICE.C_TAXAMOUNT , 
  T_PURCHASEINVOICE.C_PERIOD,
  T_PURCHASEINVOICE.C_ALTERNATEREFERENCE ,
  T_TAXRATE.C_CODE
FROM 
  T_PURCHASEINVOICE (NOLOCK) 
  JOIN T_PURCHASEINVOICE_TAXLINE (NOLOCK) ON T_PURCHASEINVOICE.C_ID = T_PURCHASEINVOICE_TAXLINE.C__OWNER_ 
  JOIN T_TAXRATE (NOLOCK) ON T_PURCHASEINVOICE_TAXLINE.C_TAXRATE = T_TAXRATE.C_ID 
WHERE 
  T_TAXRATE.C_CODE = '01' 
  AND T_PURCHASEINVOICE.C_ALTERNATEREFERENCE LIKE '%MRINV%'
  --AND T_PURCHASEINVOICE.C_TAXAMOUNT <> 0 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
  --T_PURCHASECREDITNOTE.C_ID, 
  T_PURCHASECREDITNOTE.C_DATE, 
  T_PURCHASECREDITNOTE.C_NUMBER, 
  case when T_PURCHASECREDITNOTE.C_NUMBER  = 'PCN' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END * T_PURCHASECREDITNOTE.C_NETAMOUNT , 
  case when T_PURCHASECREDITNOTE.C_NUMBER  = 'PCN' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END * T_PURCHASECREDITNOTE.C_GROSSAMOUNT ,
  case when T_PURCHASECREDITNOTE.C_NUMBER  = 'PCN' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END * T_PURCHASECREDITNOTE.C_TAXAMOUNT ,
  T_PURCHASECREDITNOTE.C_PERIOD,
  T_PURCHASECREDITNOTE.C_ALTERNATEREFERENCE,
  T_TAXRATE.C_CODE 
FROM 
  T_PURCHASECREDITNOTE (NOLOCK) 
  JOIN T_PURCHASECREDITNOTE_TAXLINE (NOLOCK) ON T_PURCHASECREDITNOTE.C_ID = T_PURCHASECREDITNOTE_TAXLINE.C__OWNER_ 
  JOIN T_TAXRATE (NOLOCK) ON T_PURCHASECREDITNOTE_TAXLINE.C_TAXRATE = T_TAXRATE.C_ID 
WHERE 
  T_TAXRATE.C_CODE = '01'
  AND T_PURCHASECREDITNOTE.C_ALTERNATEREFERENCE LIKE '%MRCR%'
  --AND T_PURCHASECREDITNOTE.C_TAXAMOUNT <> 0
```

As you can see i have commented out the `AND T_PURCHASECREDITNOTE.C_TAXAMOUNT <> 0`  and
`AND T_PURCHASEINVOICE.C_TAXAMOUNT <> 0` as that will remove every entry that has a zero tax amount.

The references i need to show are as follows `purchase credit: MRCR` and `purchase invoice: MCINV`. Below is what needs to be added to the other query, if `C_TAXAMOUNT` is zero don't show unless `C_ALTERNATIVEREFERENCE` LIKE '%MRCR%', that's how i see it unfortunately haven't got the skills to implement.

Comment: Using the editor, please add formatted text to show what your query currently generates, ***and*** then another formatted text to show what you want instead.  Please don't use images for data, etc, as described here; [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Also, read this; [NOLOCK Is Bad And You Probably Shouldn’t Use It](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2021/11/nolock-is-bad-and-you-probably-shouldnt-use-it/)

Comment: It sounds like you want all records that don't have a zero value for tax amount `OR` which have a specific reference... 
 i.e. `... AND (T_PURCHASEINVOICE.C_TAXAMOUNT <> 0  OR T_PURCHASEINVOICE.C_ALTERNATEREFERENCE LIKE '%MRINV%')`

Comment: `if` is most probably a bad solution.

Comment: @JohnLBevan thank you for your help that solved the problem much appreciated :) if you want to create an answer i will mark it correct.

Comment: RE: MatBailie's comment on `NOLOCK`, if you've just included it to ensure you don't impact others whilst you're working out your query; but you plan to remove those hints before putting your code live, an alternative would be to run `set transaction isolation level read uncommitted` in your SSMS session before running your query - that does the same (and more) as the nolock hints, but it's easiler to avoid accidentally leaving in  when you move your statement into your production code.

Comment: @MatBailie thank you for both the not uploading images and the NOLOCK i am going to edit my question and remove the image and in future do what you suggested. again thank you for the Knowledge

Comment: I know its a bit cheeky but would someone be able to mark up my question so its back to 0 please as its deducted points off my rep :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL works by filtering data, so the concept of `if` statements doesn't really apply here.  Rather you're using a condition to select what should be returned, which is what SQL's `WHERE` clause does; any rows matching the WHERE condition are returned, any which don't aren't.

You want those with zero tax `OR` those with a specific reference (including if both are true; but OR covers that too).

So you can replace:

```
AND T_PURCHASEINVOICE.C_ALTERNATEREFERENCE LIKE '%MRINV%'
--AND T_PURCHASEINVOICE.C_TAXAMOUNT <> 0
```

with

```
AND (
    T_PURCHASEINVOICE.C_ALTERNATEREFERENCE LIKE '%MRINV%'
    OR T_PURCHASEINVOICE.C_TAXAMOUNT <> 0 
)
```

Thus only if one or both of the conditions within the brackets returns true will that row be included in the results.

Comment: Just a note, `WHERE` _clause_, not statement.

Comment: Thanks @jarlh; amended.  Sorry - I'm not good on terminology.